# What to use instead of str-utils functions?

Tags: clojure, deprecated, string-utils

In http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/str-utils-api.html it is written that

```
String utilities for Clojure
Deprecated since clojure-contrib version 1.2
```

but it is not written what should I use instead. There are convenient functions like "chomp" or "re-partition" there.

What should I do to port old clojure v1.1 [code](https://github.com/tristan/clojure-infix) to the recent version? Should I just copy functions from clojure-contrib directly to the source code?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the functionality is in the [clojure.string](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.string-api.html) namespace.  E.g., `chomp` exists as `trim-newline`, `str-join` is `join`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clojure.contrib.string](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/1.2.0/clojure.contrib.string) instead of str-utils contrib

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.string)
```

Comment: Note that this is a general split out of the contrib library - each of the namespaces pretty much got their own library so they could evolve independently.  If there are other contrib items you need, check the individual libraries.

Comment: I see ["clojure.contrib.string migrated to clojure.string"](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go) phrase, but clojure.string seems to have fewer functions than clojure.contrib.string, notably there are not regex-related functions like re-partition.

Answer (score -1):

yes, I think clojure/core string and re library is better for you.